# When I try to publish website in visual studio 2013 gives an error

Tags: asp.net

**When I  try to  publish website in visual studio 2013  gives an error**

[image]

Comment: Did you read the error?  What part is unclear?

Comment: This is a problem with NTFS [max file length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio unknown build error. The fully qualified name must be less than 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434206/visual-studio-unknown-build-error-the-fully-qualified-name-must-be-less-than-26)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty explicit, the path is too long for copying the file to, it exceeds 248 characters. You should put the output of your publish to a folder closer to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like the error message states, the full path that you're trying to publish to is way too long.  When copying files in Windows, the full path needs to be less than 260 characters long.  You'll need to shorten your path somehow, most likely by trying to publish the file closer to the root directory or flattening your structure and getting rid of intermediate directories.