# Visual-studio extension project build error in "Debug" mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I created extension for Visual-studio. When I build project in "Debug" mode I get error with message `The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters`. But in "Release" mode it being build successfully.

In Debug mode project builds in folder by this path:
**"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ed6a412fExp\Extensions\CompanyName\ProjectName\1.3 + all sub folder of project"** in sum this path over 260 symbols.

I tried next options to solve this problem:

1. I set enabled for "Win32 long path" in "local group Policy Editor" dialog.
2. In file manifest of project I set next configuration

> ```
> <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>     <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="https://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
>         <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
>     </windowsSettings>
> </application>
> ```

This steps have not been helped me. Can I solve current problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio unknown build error. The fully qualified name must be less than 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434206/visual-studio-unknown-build-error-the-fully-qualified-name-must-be-less-than-26)

Comment: Moving project into root folder does not help me. Please read all description. I wrote 'In Release mode it being build successfully'.

Comment: Hi, please try to create a new solution under the same root folder and check this issue persist or not. Meanwhile, I found some others recommended to install the long path tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

1. run regedit.exe as administrator
2. locate [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
3. change data value [LongPathsEnabled] (DWORD) to "1"
4. close regedit and restart Windows

Taken from [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/fc85630e-5684-4df6-ad2f-5a128de3deef/260-character-explorer-path-length-limit?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

Answer (score 0):

Man from MSDN Support suggests try this :( [Best way to resolve file path too long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

The source where he suggests https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/784bc16e-52be-41e5-8cfd-990101e391fe/the-fully-qualified-file-name-must-be-less-than-260-characters-and-the-directory-name-must-be-less?forum=msbuild

Also, usefull links from devs https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation
Look at the second commentary from VS dev

**THUS**, using .net 4.6.2 can solve the issue i suppose